# How to merge in TFS when a file has been moved?

Tags: tfs, merge

Here's our situation:
In TFS 2010 we have the main dev branch and a release branch.
At some point, it was decided that some code was in a poorly named directory so it was renamed in TFS (only on the main branch as it wasn't a bug fiw).
I have now fixed a bug in this moved code on the dev branch and want to merge the fix into the release branch.

However, when I do this, rather than performing a merge on the file, it creates a copy of the file in the new location and labels the change as 'merge, branch'.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a 'feature' of TFS?

Update: I've just revisited this post and retried. steps to reproduce the error are:

1. I have a file (control.cs) in Main/Desktop/UserControls and
   Releases/V5/Desktop/UserControls.
2. Using source control explorer I 'Move' UserControls to UserControls2 and check in (I've also tried 'Rename' btw with the
   same results)
3. I Edit control.cs on Main and check in.
4. I merge Main into Releases/V5 (Note I am merging on the whole branch, not just UserControls)
5. I now see the modified control.cs in Releases/V5/Desktop/UserControls2 and the old one in Releases/V5/Desktop/UserControls

Comment: can you check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I answered it earlier with the assumption that you have the DEV branch and I have more inputs after I did some more research in TFS with what you explained above.

This is what I did, I have a Source branch call it Main, I branched from Main called Release. In Main, I have two folders (f1 and F2), I renamed folder F2 to F3 and checked in the changes. Then edited the file File1 within F2 (now F3) and made some changes to the content, checked in the changes.

Now I merged the Main to Release and every changes were merged properly. In Release, the folder F2 was renamed to F3 and the file1 was merged to the right folder as well.

The change should show up as merge, rename for the folder and edit for the file.

Everything worked like a charm. I am using TFS2010 as well. Can you please let me know if you have done anything differently than what I just explained above? Am i missing something?

**UPDATE:**

I tested the exact scenario that you mentioned above and it merges the control.cs file properly even after the Move/Rename in the source branch. I believe that in your case - in the Release branch someone recreated (deleted and added again) the Usercontrols folder and/or the Usercontrol.cs file, so TFS doesnt recognize that its the same file/folder from the source branch and hence its not getting merged properly.

Can you check the history of the Usercontrol file in the release branch to confirm that?

Just adding some screenshots from my test:

[image: FolderRename Pending change]

[image: This file lives within the BugTest2/BugTest3 folder]

Comment: Hi Isaiah, thanks for the response. Its a little confusing though. I think you are describing a system where there is a separate Dev branch, while we are simply doing our dev on Main. Still, if I read things right, steps 1-5 involve getting Dev and Main in sync with the new bug fix in the new folder. Fine, I don't have to worry about that. However, when step 6 is done, the merge will not apply the bug fix to the file in Release but will instead create a copy in the new location.

Comment: If your files are properly branched tfs should resolve the trail of changes as Isaiah described. The existence of another branch is irrelevant to this. I possible scenario where this wouldn't work is that the file/folder was created separate 2 times once in release and once in main - this breaks proper branching as tfs considers them completely different items.

Comment: The only thing I did differently from Isiah's modified answer is the folder rename and the file modifications were merged separately rather than all at once. In case some directory was created separately at some point instead of being properly merged as drk suggested I made a new test directory and have recreated the issue. I've kind of come to the conclusion that this is a flaw in tfs tbh rather than my error. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: So you renamed the folder in Main branch, then edited the file. Checked-in both the changes. Then you try to merge the changes from Main to Release? Can you please list the steps in the order that you did?

Comment: @Isaiah4110 Thanks for taking a look at this and sorry I didn't see your last post - i'd already given up on this. I've now retested and added exact steps to reproduce.